# Help determining the cdf

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent and $\textrm{unif}[0,1]$, and let $A$ be the area of the rectangle with sides $X$ and $Y$. Find the cdf of $A$.

First note that $A=XY$, and that the range of $A$ is $[0,1]$. Now consider the following for some $a$ in this range:
\begin{equation}
F_{A}(a)=P(XY\leq a)=\iint_{B}f(x,y)\, \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y,
\end{equation}
where B is the region given by:
\begin{equation}
B=\{(x,y):0\leq x\leq1, 0\leq y\le1,xy\leq a\}.
\end{equation}
Observe, that $f(x,y)=f_{X}(x)f_{Y}(y)=1$ by independence. Thus, the cdf of $a$ is given by:
\begin{equation}
F_{A}(a)=\iint_{B}f(x,y)\, \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y=a+\int_{a}^{1}\int_{0}^{a/x}\, \mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}x.
\end{equation}

I don't understand how the last equality is derived. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch The definition initially read with $0\le x\le1$ twice. I had removed the second copy; I guess now it was intended to be $0\le y\le1$.

Comment: Yes, it was intended to be $0\leq y\leq 1$. Sorry.

Comment: Draw a figure to help understand. This is just a two dimensional integral.

Comment: I've already tried to draw it, but I still don't get it.

Comment: Ok let me try to figure out where to draw it for you.

Comment: I just drew and posted. Let me know if it is still unclear.

Comment: @hello123123 please accept my answer if it helped you. This helps a newbie user like me a whole lot thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The domain of integration (where the support intersects the criteria) may be partitioned on whether $x<a$ or not.

$$\begin{align}B&=\{\langle x,y\rangle: 0\leqslant x\leqslant 1,0\leqslant y\leqslant 1, xy\leqslant a<1\}\\[1ex]&=\{\langle x,y\rangle:0\leqslant x\leqslant 1, 0\leqslant y\leqslant\min\{1,a/x\}\}\\[1ex]&=\{\langle x,y\rangle:(0\leqslant x<a, 0\leqslant y\leqslant 1)\vee(a\leqslant x\leqslant 1, 0\leqslant y\leqslant a/x)\}\end{align}$$

Thus:

$$\begin{align}F_A(a)&=\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant a\lt 1}\cdotp\iint_{B} f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,\mathrm d\langle x,y\rangle+\mathbf 1_{1\leqslant a}\\[1ex]&=\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant a\lt 1}\cdotp\left(\int_0^1\int_0^{\min\{1,a/x\}}1\,\mathrm d y\,\mathrm d x\right)+\mathbf 1_{1\leqslant a}\\[1ex]&=\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant a\lt 1}\cdotp\left(\int_0^a\int_0^1 1\,\mathrm d y\,\mathrm d x+\int_a^1\int_0^{a/x}1\,\mathrm d y\,\mathrm d x\right)+\mathbf 1_{1\leqslant a}\\[1ex] &= \mathbf 1_{0\leqslant a\lt 1}\cdotp\left(a+\int_a^1\int_0^{a/x}1\,\mathrm d y\,\mathrm d x\right)+\mathbf 1_{1\leqslant a}&&\bigstar\\[1ex]&=\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant a\lt 1}\cdotp\left(a+\int_a^1 ax^{-1}\mathrm d x\right)+\mathbf 1_{1\leqslant a}\\[2ex]&=\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant a\lt 1}\cdotp\left(a-a\ln a\right)+\mathbf 1_{1\leqslant a}\\[4ex]F_A(a)&=\begin{cases}0&:&\hspace{4.25ex} a\lt 0\\a-a\ln a&:& 0\leqslant a\lt 1\\1&:&1\leqslant a\end{cases}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Hope this helps? The limits of integration are to integrate over this shaded region

Comment: I still can't seem to figure out why they add $a$ before they integrate. And are you sure that the drawing holds in general; For instance what if the point $a$ was chosen a little to the right, would the limit of the first integral still be from $a$ to $1$ or?

Comment: they a comes from the area of rectangle on the left of the shaded region. Also note $0<a<1$.

Comment: @hello123123 The problem is to integrate over the intersection of the rectangle with the unbounded region between the x axis and $xy=a$. The top of this region is the smaller of 1 and $a/x$. So you could have made the x bounds go from 0 to 1 provided you made the y bounds go from 0 to $\min(1,a/x)$.

Comment: you could, and it will give you exactly the same answer. because for $x<a$ note that $min(1,a/x)$ is simply 1. (hence, giving that $a$ term) Does that make sense?